# How to combine two PHP arrays and display results according to index number?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, indexing

I created two arrays. First the arrays show the elements with no order whatsoever. So, I have to sort them first by alphabetical order and lowest-to-highest. Once in order, the two arrays that need to be combined in such way that each element from each array are **combined according to their index number**.

**My goal:** a0 b1 c2 d3 e4 f5 g6

**What I'm getting:** abcdefg0123456

```
$array1 = array("b", "f", "g", "a", "c", "d", "e");
    $array2 = array("5", "0", "1", "4", "3", "2", "6");
    sort($array1);
    sort($array2);

    echo "<pre> \n";
    print_r($array1);
    echo "</pre> \n";

    echo "<pre> \n";
    print_r($array2);
    echo "</pre> \n";

    echo "<h3 style='font-family:Helvetica'>Combining Arrays</h3>";
    $array3 = array_merge($array1, $array2);


    for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
    {
        for($j = 0; $j < 7; $j++)
        {
            echo $array3[$i] [$j];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your Question is pretty confusing I mean your goal is something like a0 b1 c2 d3 e4 f5 g6 but how are you supposed to know that a is to be combined with 0, does this mean you're trying to map alphabets with number like a0 b1, well by the looks of just those two arrays how is this possible ?? Are you sure this is what you need ? It might that I am wrong but this does look pretty confusing are you trying to get answer like b5 f0 g1 ...

Comment: Sorry for the misuderstanding. So the original arrays contain letters and number with no order. Then I had to sort alphabetically and lowest to highest. Once ordered, I need to combine the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can not be done by array_merge. Use simple loop.

```
    $array1 = array("b", "f", "g", "a", "c", "d", "e");
    $array2 = array("5", "0", "1", "4", "3", "2", "6");
    sort($array1);
    sort($array2);
    for($j = 0; $j < 7; $j++){
        echo "{$array1[$j]}{$array2[$j]} ";
    }
```

http://ideone.com/LLdVm

Comment: How does that give an answer that he wants ?? doesn't that give like b5 f0 g1 .... ??

Comment: It's giving me `aa bb cc dd ee ff gg` which is at least closer than what I got :)

Comment: It works! (I hadn't noticed $array1 was repeated twice!) Thank you very much.

One more question, what's the use of the curly braces in this case?

Comment: oops I seem to have missed the sort part there, this should work, sorry

Comment: See complex curly syntax in http://bd.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc

Answer (score 0):

`array_merge` knows nothing about the order you want them sorted in. It even knows nothing of whether the contents are letters or numbers, let alone indexes of the alphabet corresponding to the contents of the prior array!

In short, you can't use `array_merge` to do what you want. You just need to create your own loop that will solve the problem.

Your code doesn't even make sense - you have two one-dimensional arrays which you concatenate then print as if they were a two dimensional array??

Comment: What do I need to use then? As you can see, I have no experience on PHP. I need help please.

Answer (score 0):

I think he just wants one array with elements as he stated:

```
a0 b1 c2 d3 e4 f5 g6
```

This should work:

```
$array3 = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
  $array3[] = $array1[$i].$array2[$i];
}
echo "<pre> \n";
print_r($array3);
echo "</pre> \n";
```

Comment: I suppose by his example, maybe he doesn't want a combined array but just the output.

Comment: Correct, the output is my goal.

Comment: Then replace the last three lines with: foreach($array3 as $item){echo "$item ";} and you will be able to further manipulate $array3, or just output directly according to @shiplu.mokadd.im's answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to **combine** - using `array_combine`:

```
    $array1 = array("b", "f", "g", "a", "c", "d", "e");
        $array2 = array("5", "0", "1", "4", "3", "2", "6");
        sort($array1);
        sort($array2);

        echo "<pre> \n";
        print_r($array1);
        echo "</pre> \n";

        echo "<pre> \n";
        print_r($array2);
        echo "</pre> \n";

        echo "<h3 style='font-family:Helvetica'>Combining Arrays</h3>";

//        $array3 = array_merge($array1, $array2);


        $array3 = array_combine($array1, $array2);


        echo "<pre> \n";
        print_r($array3);
        echo "</pre> \n";

        foreach($array3 as $letter => $number){
            echo "$letter:$number <br />";
        }
```